# How to convert an operator into a character in R

Tags: r

```
##The example is:
xyTrain <- cbind(yTrain$V2, xTrain) 
print(xyTrain)
```

[image: Result is]

```
## cannot change the name using the function below.
xyTrain <- rename(yTrain, yTrain$V2 = Activity) 
##Error: unexpected '=' in "xyTrain <- rename(yTrain, yTrain$V2 ="
```

Regarding the error above: it seems the problem iss with '$'... It is supposed to be a character, but it is an operator currently. How can I change it?

Comment: `colnames(xyTrain)[1] <- "Activity"` ?

Comment: @Henning Lee could you add a tag to the packages you are using? `rename()` is not a part of base R.

Comment: @Imo  it is dplyr packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `backticks` to select the variables that have unusual names.  Based on the OP's example, we are changing the 'yTrain$V2' to 'Activity'.  In that case 'Activity' should be on the `lhs` of `=`.

```
dplyr::rename(yTrain, Activity = `yTrain$V2`)
#          Activity
#1 WALKING_UPSTAIRS
#2 WALKING_UPSTAIRS
#3 WALKING_UPSTAIRS
```

Was able to replicate the 'Error' by using the OP's code

```
dplyr::rename(yTrain, yTrain$V2 = Activity) 
#Error: unexpected '=' in "dplyr::rename(yTrain, yTrain$V2 ="
```

#### data

```
 yTrain <- data.frame("yTrain$V2" = rep("WALKING_UPSTAIRS", 3), 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```